# jQuery Datepicker with Select elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to find a date of birth date picker similar to the one next to the bottom on this page: http://www.pradosoft.com/demos/quickstart/?page=Controls.Samples.TDatePicker.Home

Have you seen such date picker in jQuery ?.

Comment: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-datepicker-22-2-2011

Comment: Yes there are plenty.  Just google `jquery datapicker` also there's one in the jQuery UI which comes up as the first result which is.  IN particular this http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#dropdown-month-year example is similar to your question.  This question shouldn't be on here in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I actually use a combination of the day selector with dropdowns from the [jQuery UI datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) for birthday selection like so:

```
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({
        changeYear:true,
        changeMonth:true,
        showMonthAfterYear:true,
        yearRange:'1920:' + $.datepicker.formatDate('yy', new Date())
    });
```